# Receive http $_POST and feed into SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, http-post

I'm currently trying to setup a page which receives XML via an HTTP POST. I have successfully used SimpleXML to retrieve the XML from a file and then perform my logic, but I am unsure how to set it up to receive a POST submission.

Is there a default way to retrieve all information from $_POST as a string?

```
//'get'ting the xml from a file
$job = simplexml_load_file(/path/to/file);

//my assumption on how to accept the XML post - throws a not string error
$job = simplexml_load_string($_POST);
```

As the is being received from a third party, is there extra information that I am not being supplied? All my previous handlings have been with name=value pairs, i.e. `$value = $_POST['name'];` To rephrase, do all HTTP POSTs have a name handle to them?

Sorry for the multi-faceted question, I'm a bit lost, so am trying to cover all angles.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are u receiving path to file in $_POST ?

Comment: As $_POST itself is an array, I hope this would help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely looking for the [raw POST data](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php).

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will combine all posted variables into a single string variable:

```
$foo = "";
foreach( $_POST as $val )
{
    $foo .= $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if you are receiving xml with using post, why not are you using [xmlrpc](http://php.net/xmlrpc_decode)?